# Typescript `esModuleInterop` ignored with module import

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, ecmascript-2017, flamelink-cms

I'm trying to import this module into my Typescript file but it is throwing an error about how the module is imported. This is a Google Firebase Function script but I am importing this module in other areas of my project code just fine.

```
10 const flamelinkApp = flamelink({
                        ~~~~~~~~~

  src/index.ts:3:1
    3 import * as flamelink from 'flamelink/app';
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.
```

NMy Typescript config file is here:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

and you'll see that the `esModuleInterop` flag is set to true, which is supposed to fix this issue.

I also tried the import like this:
`import flamelink from 'flamelink/app';`
and get this error:

```
Module '"/Users/leeprobert/Documents/dev/PebbleStudios/Sciex/Grace/dev/pebble_sciex_grace_react/client/functions/node_modules/flamelink/public"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flagts(1259)
public.d.ts(61, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem with importing moment. Pls update, if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the warning message it seems to me that we need to import the module's default instead of in a namespace. Could u try this ?

```
import flamelink from 'flamelink/app'
```

Comment: I tried this. Will edit my post to reflect that error.

Comment: That error suggests that esModuleInterop is not turned on. Can you make sure esModuleInterop is turned on ? Perhaps the tsconfig is overridden somewhere. I found the same issue here https://github.com/flamelink/flamelink-js-sdk/issues/58

Comment: Interesting! The Cloud Function deploy via CLI works, so the error in my code is related to VSCode's realtime compiler and not the deploy process. But I have that flag set in my global tsconfig too. So, not sure how to subdue that error.